# Sum of Sine Fits

Tags: python, linear-regression, curve-fitting, statsmodels

I have some sample data found below that I'm attempting to make two curve fits to. The first is a fit based on the sum of sines and cosines which I was able to do using the statsmodels OLS function.

[image]

```
ny = len(y_arr)
nparams = 5

xa1 = np.cos(2*np.pi*1*x_arr)
xb1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*1*x_arr)
xa2 = np.cos(2*np.pi*2*x_arr)
xb2 = np.sin(2*np.pi*2*x_arr)

matr = np.ones((ny,nparams),dtype=float)
matr[:,1] = xa1
matr[:,2] = xb1
matr[:,3] = xa2
matr[:,4] = xb2

model = sm.OLS(y_arr, matr)
results = model.fit()
print(results.summary())
```

This gave me coefficients of a0 = 1.1463, a1 = -3.928, b1 = 0.5352, a2 = -0.4091, b2 = -0.3514

However, now I want to do use this information to compute the fit in terms of a sum of sine functions where amplitude and phase are given, i.e.:

[image]

From what I've seen, OLS can't handle the sum of sine fits when having to compute amplitude and phases concurrently. Is there another package that anyone here has used to do similar fits?

Answer (score 0):

Those series are closely related:

```
A_k = sqrt(a_k**2 + b_k**2)
phi_k = -atan(b_k/a_k)
```

So, having calculated `a_k` and `b_k` you can easily get `A_k` and `phi_k`
using the transformation above.

Comment: I'm now embarrassed for posting because I didn't think of it as a simple math problem that I've probably done many times before. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help!